# Evenly arranging circular points in Lua

Tags: lua, love2d

I managed to make points via the print function appear in a circle shape and animated it to go in a constant rotation with the circle variable. However my attempt to auto arrange the points into a 1/number of points segments of the circle to make them laid out evenly without inputting the angle of each one seems instead to make them go around far more than 360 degrees around the circle, as it feeds into itself.

For example for 5 points I'd want each circle in 1/5th of the 360 degrees with even space on each side, which should make a regular pentagon shape if you joined up the dots

```
function love.load() --Only run at startup
    cycle = 0
    points = 9 -- should work on any value
    radius = 0.5
    love.window.setMode(90, 90)
end
function love.update()
    cycle = cycle + 0.05
    if cycle >= 360 then
        cycle = 0
        --prevent huge values
    end
end 
function love.draw()
    i = 0
    while i < points do
        x = radius * math.deg(math.sin(cycle + (360 * (i / points )) )  ) 
        y = radius * math.deg(math.cos(cycle + (360 * (i / points )) )  )
        --cycle to move and i + 1 / points to auto arrange
        b = (i / points )
        b = round(b, 2)
        love.graphics.print( b , 33 + x, 33 + y)
        i = i + 1
    end
end
function round(num, idp) --rounding function for display
    local mult = 10^(idp or 0)
    return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end
```

What currently happens:

[image: img]

Comment: This is what happens currently http://i.imgur.com/58tjZqx.png

Answer (score 4):

In your loop, you're doing

```
x = radius * math.deg(math.sin(cycle + (360 * (i / points )) )  ) 
y = radius * math.deg(math.cos(cycle + (360 * (i / points )) )  )
```

whereas, you want to have:

```
b = i / points
local c = cycle + (360 * b)            -- to lessen the computation cost
x = radius * math.sin( math.rad(c) ) 
y = radius * math.cos( math.rad(c) )
```

Comment: Thanks, though would that actually correct the currently messed up arrangement of the points?

Comment: The current arrangement of point appears so because you are using a `string` (or `number`) to be displayed instead of simple lines or points.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I read the answer the wrong way up. You may want to switch the order of the code blocks for clarity. Cheers! :)

Comment: I don't really understand you hjpotter?

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to convert that 360 to radians using the lua math.rad() function, as lua's math.sin(O) and math.cos() functions go by radians rather than degrees. the excalamation point have nothing to do with code and are just there to grab your attention to the problem.

```
        x =  math.deg(radius*math.sin(cycle + (!!!math.rad(360)!!! * (i / points )) )  ) 
        y =  math.deg(radius*math.cos(cycle + (!!!math.rad(360)!!! * (i / points )) )  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cos for x and sin for y to get the right order:

```
x = radius * math.deg(math.cos(cycle + (360 * (i / points )) )  ) 
y = radius * math.deg(math.sin(cycle + (360 * (i / points )) )  )
```